# remote form web app

Tags: php, javascript, curl

I would like to implement my own personal web application which takes a bunch of personal information & fills out a job application on a remotely different website. The language I intend to use is PHP. Based on some articles on the web, php_curl might be the thing I would use for this scenario.

I'd like to get some advice on this particular topic (using php to manipulate remote websites) because I don't have much experience with php_curl.

I'd like to know if this type of web application is possible with javascript / php / mysql? What technologies should I be using, or what type of pitfalls would I run into?

*This is similar to an already asked question, but I remade it because I was having trouble viewing any answers on the post.

Comment: Is it just a single remote website that you are trying to post data to?

Comment: no, I'm taking personal information from my little web application and using the information provided to fill out job applications for multiple places at once.  This is meant to simplify the job application process.

Comment: I would assume each of the site(s) you are referring to have some kind of restful API?

Comment: I'm unsure about the restful API.  Does it matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will likely spend much more time trying to build an automated solution to do this than you would actually just filling out the form manually.  Even if each site had an API to enter this information (which would be the easiest way to do this), each integration might take as long as just cutting/pasting your information into the website.

If there are no API's you would need to figure out to basically forge POST requests to each site at the point where the forms are submitted.  You would likely need to store and send cookies through a login process to be able to do things like deal with managing session cookies.

I just don't see a viable way forward for you.

Comment: Alright, thanks.  This project sounded cool in my mind, but I guess I'll have to find something else.